# Integral on a particular interval where there is a negative sign under root and sin^{-1}(x)>1

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to solve integral: $$f(x)=\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$$ 
The general solution of this integral has terms in form of $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ and $\sin^{-1} \frac{x}{2}$

I'm trying to solve this integral for a case where the upper limit of $x$ is $x > a$.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: what mean : "to solve an integral" ?

Comment: Why do you expect the integral to be any different?

Comment: For the upper limit great than $a$, the integrand is not defined in real space. But, you may rewrite it as $i\sqrt{x^2-a^2}$ to proceed, leading to a complex value

Comment: Surb - my apologies if my terminology is incorrect, I'm a non-mathematician who ended up with this particular problem. Sorry if the above sounds crass.

PeterForeman - I didn't understand your question, sorry. If I have, say, $x=6$ and $a=2$ then I need to find a $sin$ of an angle that will return $3$. I don't know how to do that.

Quanto - Thank you for that, but given that this problem is an evaluation of a line integral. Not sure if introducing $i$ is what the problem author was asking for.

Thank you all kindly for responses.

Comment: Keep in mind $\sin\theta \le1$. So, it can not be 3.

Comment: @Quanto - Well that is what I'm struggling with. Say my case is example 8. as given on [this page](http://www.sosmath.com/tables/integral/integ13/integ13.html). Say I have an integral of $\sqrt{4-x^{2}}$, and interval from 0 to 6. This gives me ${\sqrt{2^{2}-6^{2}}}$ and ${sin^{-1}(\frac{6}{2})}$ in the solution, and that's where I'm stuck. Thanks again.

Comment: I provided the explanation in the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you examine the domain of the function

$$f(x)=\sqrt{4- x^2}$$

it is

$$4-x^2\ge 0$$

which is,

$$ -2 \le x \le 2$$

Therefore, the function $f(x)$ is undefined for $x>2$, and the upper bound of the integral is $2$ at the most and can not be 6.